# Nginx SSL connection refused, but works locally

Tags: ssl, nginx, connection-refused

I have a problem with Nginx SSL setting. I have a default setting of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

I tried with a very simple setting in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`:

```
server
{
    listen                 80;
    server_name            sub.mydomain.com;
    return                 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    # This root works
    #root                   /var/www/html;
}

server
{
    listen                 443 default_server ssl;
    server_name            sub.mydomain.com;
    ssl                    on;
    ssl_certificate        /var/www/html/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key    /var/www/html/key.pem;
    root                   /var/www/html;
}
```

HTTP works, but not HTTPS. I get connection refused when running:

```
curl -v https://sub.mydomain.com
```

I have tried setting /etc/hosts to:

```
127.0.0.1    sub.mydomain.com
```

There is no problem and I can see the green SSL bar if I access the page using the web browser in the server locally. But, I still get connection refused if I access the page externally using a different computer.

I have also tried enabling the Ubuntu firewall and allowing SSL via:

```
ufw allow 443
```

It does not work.

There is no error in the log file of the Nginx

### Edit 1

I have tried `listen 0.0.0.0:80` and `listen 0.0.0.0:443` and still does not work

The output of the `netstat -nlp | grep nginx`:

```
tcp    0    0 0.0.0.0:80     0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN    12591/nginx -g daem
tcp    0    0 0.0.0.0:443    0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN    12591/nginx -g daem
```

Can anyone help please? Thanks.

Comment: Try changing `listen                 80;` to `listen                 0.0.0.0:80;`, and the same for `443`.

Comment: Also show output of `netstat -nlp | grep nginx`

Comment: `ufw allow ssl` gives an error on my system since ssl is not a defined service. Did you mean `ufw allow https` ??

Comment: Sorry, I mean `ufw allow 443`

Comment: So, it's listening on all interfaces. Where is this hosted; EC2 by chance? Requests might be getting blocked by an external firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by opening the port 433 in the router. I forget to open the port when I change the router.

Thanks Will for giving the idea about the external firewall.